# Escape reserved characters in a list by adding backslash in front of it

Tags: python, regex, string, list

```
reserved_chars = "? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -"

list_vals = ['gold-bear@gmail.com', 'P&G@dom.com', 'JACKSON! BOT', 'annoying\name']
```

What is that fastest way to loop through every element in a list and add a \ in front of the reserved character if one of the elements contains them?

desired output:

```
fixed_list = ['gold\-bear@gmail.com', 'P\&G@dom.com', 'JACKSON\! BOT', 'annoying\\name']
```

Comment: This is not valid python - you need to escape at least the `"` inside your string to make this possible at all - or use """ and """ front and back to delimit the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make a translation table with `str.maketrans()` and pass that into translate. This takes a little setup, but you can reuse the translation table and it's quite fast:

```
reserved_chars = '''?&|!{}[]()^~*:\\"'+-'''
list_vals = ['gold-bear@gmail.com', 'P&G@dom.com', 'JACKSON! BOT', 'annoying\\name']

# make trans table
replace = ['\\' + l for l in reserved_chars]
trans = str.maketrans(dict(zip(reserved_chars, replace)))

# translate with trans table
fixed_list = [s.translate(trans) for s in list_vals]

print("\n".join(fixed_list))
```

Prints:

```
gold\-bear@gmail.com
P\&G@dom.com
JACKSON\! BOT
annoying\\name
```

Comment: did not know maketrans works also for 1 to many transformations - nice one

Comment: @PatrickArtner — yeah it's not obvious, but you can pass it a dict for multi-character replacement.

Comment: hi, you're very close, the final ouput has to be a list, and the last element has 'annoying\name' has one backslash in it

Comment: @TH14 in the answer `fixed_list` is a list. If you look at your question, your desired output has 'annoying\\name' because the backslash has to be escaped (unless you want a new line `\n` in there.

Comment: yes the desired output should have 'annoying\\name' but in your list_vals list it's 'annoying\\name'

Comment: Forgive me @TH14, but I'm having difficulty seeing the difference between those two values. `'annoying\\name' ` == `'annoying\\name'` Remember in string literals in python backslashes get escaped with backslashed.

Comment: the list_vals in my question has 'annoying\name' not 'annoying\\name'

Comment: @TH14 that would make that string `annoying<newline>ame` is that really what it's supposed to be? If it's supposed to have a slash character in it, the way you write that in python is ''annoying\\name", which will print as 'annoying\name' (without a new line).

Comment: no, i want to turn 'annoying\name' into 'annoying\\name', I am going to be appending all the elements to another list and running a query

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm this is what I'm trying to use

Comment: @TH14 the point I'm trying to make is that the string "annoying\name"  doesn't actually have a backslash in it. It has a newline character. Type this into python: print('annoying\name') you won't see a "\". If you want a string that prints (and means) 'annoying\name' you need to write that as 'annoying\\name' — this will print as 'annoying\name'

Comment: i understand, sorry i shouldve added more context, i'm going to be taking that fixed_list and looping over it and using f strings to fill in placeholders in a query, 
i.e for i in fixed_list:
               query =( f" select .... from...where...val = {i}"), the query will otherwise throw an error. If any of the reserved characters are in there

Comment: @TH14 then you should probably write the strings as raw strings like r'annoying\name'  -- this will work with the translation and interpret backslashes as backlashes.

Comment: how would I convert the elements in my list to raw string?

Comment: @TH14. Raw strings are a python literal thing. You don't convert them — it's how you represent them in code. This is one byte: '\n', `0x0a => newline`, This is two bytes: r'\n'  `0x5c` `0x6e` => backslash and n. If you are passing python strings to salesforce, I doubt you will need to escape newline characters — it's not actually a backslash, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fast way - you got strings, strings are immuteable, you need to create new ones.

Probably best way is to build your own translation dictionary and do the grunt work yourself:

```
reserved = """? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -"""

tr = { c:f"\\{c}" for c in reserved}
print(tr)
data = ['gold-bear@gmail.com', 'P&G@dom.com', 'JACKSON! BOT', 'annoying\name']

transformed = [ ''.join(tr.get(letter,letter) for letter in word) for word in data]

for word in transformed:
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
# translation dictionary
{'?': '\\?', ' ': '\\ ', '&': '\\&', '|': '\\|', '!': '\\!', '{': '\\{', 
 '}': '\\}', '[': '\\[', ']': '\\]', '(': '\\(', ')': '\\)', '^': '\\^', 
 '~': '\\~', '*': '\\*', ':': '\\:', '\\': '\\\\', '"': '\\"', "'": "\\'", 
 '+': '\\+', '-': '\\-'}

# transformed strings  
gold\-bear@gmail.com
P\&G@dom.com
JACKSON\!\ BOT
annoying
ame
```

---

*Sidenotes:*

- Your example missed to escape the space inside `'JACKSON\! BOT'`.
- The `repl()` of the `transformed` list looks "wrongly" escaped because when printing it escapes each `'\'` itself again - whats being printed see wordlist

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the fastest, but could be the easiest to code. Make a regex that does it for you, and run re.sub, like this:

```
import re

reserved_chars = "?&|!{}[]()^~*:\\\"'+-"
replace_regex = "([" + ''.join('\\x%x' % ord(x) for x in reserved_chars) + "])"

list_vals = ['gold-bear@gmail.com', 'P&G@dom.com', 'JACKSON! BOT', r'annoying\name']
escaped_vals = [re.sub(replace_regex, r"\\\1", x) for x in list_vals]
```

Again, just to clarify, regexes are SLOW.

Comment: I get this output, ['gold\\-bear@gmail.com', 'P\\&G@dom.com', 'JACKSON\\! BOT', 'annoying\\\\name'], there only should be one backslash infront of the reserved char

Comment: Its your output escaping the backslashes again. Print with something like this: `for x in escaped_vals: print(x)`

Comment: I'm appending the elements to another list not just printing them

Comment: You are printing it at some point, directly, or converting it with str() and alike to string. This will escape the backslashes. The re.sub above does **not** add extra backslashes. I've just ran it and printed the output with `print(','.join(escaped_vals))`, getting `gold\-bear@gmail.com,P\&G@dom.com,JACKSON\! BOT,annoying\\name` output. With a simple `print(escaped_vals)` i do get `['gold\\-bear@gmail.com', 'P\\&G@dom.com', 'JACKSON\\! BOT', 'annoying\\\\name']`, and i am nearly 100% sure you end up doing something similar.